# duplicate an instance but cannot access the new private IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spotfire, amazon-ami

I make an AMI from my original ec2 instance, then launch it with the same parameters. Everything seem like working fine, but when I connect to the new instance virtual machine, I cannot access the private IP or the public IP address of that instance on the browser. And the weird thing is that localhost is accessible, even the private and public IP address of the original instance is accessible in the new instance virtual machine. I am new to AWS so I hope someone know what happen here. Thank guys

Answer (score 0):

Check that:

1. Your security group for the new instance has the same rules as the old instance.
2. That you have launched your new EC2 into a subnet that is accessible via the internet.

Comment: I use the same security group and subnet with the old one. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Using the same SG is and subnet is fine. Are you running a web server on the instances and if yes, what type of web server?

Comment: If you are running apache for example check your http.conf file for any hardcoding of the server details, maybe it is still has the details of the old server in the new configuration.

Comment: I run Spotfire Server. It said to be a Tomcat web application

Comment: Then maybe check your configuration of the Spotfire server, maybe something is still set in there that is configured for your old server. Also check the Spotfire log files to see if you make the connection, but the web server throws an error. If you are running it on Windows check that the Windows Firewal allows for connections on the port that Spotfire is serving.